# Jquery DateTimePicker not visible

Tags: jquery, vb.net, razor

I'm trying to implement this http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ to my project.

The problem is that nothing happens.

So, here is what I've done and not removed :

-I've downloaded the .js file and put it inside the "Scripts" file.
-I added a reference to this script that way :

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I've added this at the beginning of the page :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('.datetime').datetimepicker();
});
 </script>
```

I've added this at the end of the css file :

```
 /* css for timepicker */
 .ui-timepicker-div .ui-widget-header { margin-bottom: 8px; }
 .ui-timepicker-div dl { text-align: left; }
 .ui-timepicker-div dl dt { height: 25px; margin-bottom: -25px; }
 .ui-timepicker-div dl dd { margin: 0 10px 10px 65px; }
 .ui-timepicker-div td { font-size: 90%; }
 .ui-tpicker-grid-label { background: none; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

And I've also this :

```
 <input type="text" class="datetime" id="datetime1" value="" />
```

The problem is that there is only the textbox that is displayed. The timepicker isn't. What haven't I well understand?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go demo for you as well : http://jsfiddle.net/atP2P/

**HTML**

class was missing

```
<script src="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input type="text" name="datetime" id="datetime1" class="datetime" value="" />
​
```

Comment: thx for the fiddle. Bue copy/pasting exactly your code doesn't work... I don't get what's the problem here

Comment: Hiya @patxy use this as source `<script src="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` instead of your @url and try again please :) let me know how it goes. Cheers

Comment: it doesn't change anything :-(

Comment: hmmm... can you give more details bruv, put debugger or alert('foo'); in you javascript code and see if that alerts or debugger hits or not, cheers! **definetly something to do with the dodgy thingy in your DOM. *

Comment: $(function () {
        $('.datetime').datetimepicker();
        alert("test");
    });
doing this, the alert is never fired

Comment: perfect put alert **before** the datepicker function called, don't worry we will sort it out mate :) let me know if alert fired or not. cheers

Comment: cool so here you  BINGO - it does not recognize the api .datepicker() hence source is not there for api `<script src="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/js/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` **BUT** to further make it sure do **alert($('.datetime').attr('id'));** before the api got called, will wait for your reply. cheers :)

Comment: it hadn't been fired, what do I have to do now? finding another library?

Comment: @patxy you tried doing this alert - alert($('.datetime').attr('id')); and this alert will return the id of your input - just to check if input is recognized - further don't worry - Its funny that sourcing the add-on.js doesn't to anything what version of Jquery you are using? cheers

Comment: @patxy man I bet you are missing jquery ui http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui/  :)) **see it doesn't work if I remove Jquery UI like in this demo** http://jsfiddle.net/atP2P/1/

Comment: excuse me... I made a syntax error... This alert is well fired, and returning the good id

Comment: For the version I use... I'm not really sure :-(. I'm developing for 2 months. So, in the _Layout.vbhtml, the only script that is called is this one : <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>. However, in the file "Scripts", there is Jquery-ui-1.8.11 that is there. I'm adding it, and I'll come back

Comment: thx a lot, there was the problem. I still have a little one. Might be due to the css. I don't see a great timepicker. I don't have any buttons and so on. I also don't see a good one inside the fiddle. What should I have done with the css?

Comment: @patxy YAY!! nice! (don't forget to accept my answer lolz) yeah it definitely must be css If I may suggest go to this link you gave and rigt click and see the view source and source the css to your page as well http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ rest everything seems normal now, have a nice one, cheers! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your are using class `.datetime` while initializing the plugin. So your HTML should have class in them

```
 <input type="text" name="datetime" id="datetime1" class="datetime" value="" />
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5CGVZ/)

Or, you can initialize your plugin to select the `id` instead of the class like:

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetime1').datetimepicker();
});
```

Either way, it will work.

Comment: Sorry, I did not give the good code. It didn't work with the class before, and I don't know why I had removed it. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @Starx Bruv you used my jsfiddle just mentioning rest all cool! have a good one! :)) cheers!

Comment: @Tats_innit, Yes I did :), but I changed it now Ha ha

Comment: @Starx :)) No worries bruv! Howz it going! :) lolz Pleasure you used it have a nice one, cheers

Answer (score 2):

you have to change this

```
 <input type="text" name="datetime" id="datetime1" value="" />
```

to this

```
 <input type="text" name="datetime" class ="datetime" id="datetime1" value="" />
```

since you are using css class selector to select the dom element you have to specify the class attribute of that element so that the dateimepicker can find the control with the class="datetime"

or optionally you can change your script with the id selector like this if you dont want to use css class on the input element

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetime1').datetimepicker();
});
```

[**this**](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp) will give you a nice idea about jquery and selectors

Comment: Sorry, I did not give the good code. It didn't work with the class before, and I don't know why I had removed it. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @patxy check firebug or ie developer tools for errors if there are
also please ensure that you included the reference to the jquery.js in your code(head element)

Answer (score 2):

Or you can change

```
$('.datetime').datetimepicker();
```

to

```
$('#datetime1').datetimepicker();
```

If you really want to use classes, try this:

```
$('.datetime').each(function() {
    $(this).datetimepicker();
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not give the good code. It didn't work with the class before, and I don't know why I had removed it. It still doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried this version? The class selector will return an array of items and the datetimepicker may struggle with those. Try this. I will also update my answer for the class case.

Answer (score 2):

try adding class attribute of the textbox as "datetime"

Comment: Sorry, I did not give the good code. It didn't work with the class before, and I don't know why I had removed it. It still doesn't work